# Win 10 Pro time sync problems

Tags: windows, time

I've problems with time synchronization on my laptop...
so I've been tried all steps from  [this link](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-computer-did-not-resync-because-no-time-data-was-available-error-on-windows/) but nothing worked... error still there...
can any one help with advice what I can do to solve this problem?

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎25.‎08.‎2020
OS build    19045.3208
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0
```